# Как добиться нужного эффекта вывода надписи?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Как сделать чтобы `TextBlock` который выводит `"N"`, отрисовал надпись фоном который стоит на `Label`?

```
        <Label Height="150"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Label.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="design-1377545.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
            </Label.Background>
            <Label.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Opacity="0.8">
                    <Grid>
                        <Polygon HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Fill="White"
                                 Points="0 40, 20 80, 80 80, 100 40, 80 0, 20 0"
                                 Stroke="White" />
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="75"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   Text="N" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**. Придумал такой вариант, но так заметно что `N` не прозрачная, а просто отрисовывается точно таким же фоном как и лейбл.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="brush" ImageSource="design-1377545.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
</Window.Resources>
<TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource brush}"
           Text="N">
</TextBlock>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE2.** Нарисовал в `Paint` какой приблизительно эффект хочу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает приведённый вами же код?

Comment: @VladD, Буква `N` отображается черным цветом,а хочется чтобы она стала прозрачной и отрисовалась цветом фона лейбла. Если прям под буквой есть какие линии, то они должны отрисоватся на букве.

Comment: Не понятно. :( У вас есть картинка, показывающая, как должно выглядеть?

Comment: @VladD, Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Агааааа! Понял, сейчас придумаю что-нибудь.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает ваш вариант из Update? Он же вроде то, что надо?

Comment: @VladD, да, он не плохой, но ваш вариант получше.

Comment: У VisualBrush преимущество в том, что на источнике можно добавлять любой контент, и он весь отобразится. С `ImageBrush ` копируется только картинка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует несколько путей. Например, работает через `VisualBrush` (это такая штука, которая умеет склонировать внешний вид куска контента в виде кисти.

Итак, приступим. Для начала, нам нужен чистый фон. Поэтому внешний `Label` убираем, и всю конструкцию кладём в `Grid`. Затем, кусок с фоном кладём в отдельный `Grid`, без child-элементов. А для `TextBlock`'а указываем `Foreground`. Поскольку вы не дали картинку, я вместо неё использовал `RadialGradientBrush` сумасшедших цветов. А ещё я к `TextBlock`'у добавил `Margin` для лучшей визуальной центровки, и снизил Opacity до 0.5 для красоты.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="BgSource">
        <Grid.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5"
                    RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
    <Polygon HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Fill="White"
             Points="0 40, 20 80, 80 80, 100 40, 80 0, 20 0"
             Stroke="White"
             Opacity="0.5" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               TextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="75"
               Text="N"
               Margin="0,0,0,7">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <!-- вся магия тут -->
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=BgSource}" Stretch="None"/>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Получается вот такой результат:

[image: ужасные цвета, правда?]

---

Другое решение — через `OpacityMask` — изложено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559748/276994).

Comment: `VisualBrush` даже не знал. Спасибо, получилось прикольно!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!